# How can I pull existing classes from SFDC instance

Tags: mavensmate

I am loving MM and have what I think is a fairly easy question.

I have a fair amount of co=de in an org and would like to pull all of it down to my Macbook and work on it in MM. How can I do that? I can see that I can deploy the code and have been able to do that without a problem. I want to 'pull' not 'push'.

Many thanks, 
Mark

Comment: Create a new project and that should allow you to select all metadata you want to pull

Comment: OK that makes sense but what if others have contributed to the org. You really dont want to create a new project so that you can work on their code. 

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I went to Mavensmate->Project-> Edit Project->Project Metadata (Tab) and clicked on Refresh.

Everything pulled down.

I dont know if this is the 'right' way but it worked for me.